# Flutter update listview from parent

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a list of objects that can be changed depending on user behaviour or response from the backend.

I created `StatefulWidget` that I can use in several places in my app

```
class EventList extends StatefulWidget {
final List<EventListModel> models;

EventList({Key key, this.models}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
 return _EventListState();
 }
}

class _EventListState extends State<EventList> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return ListView(
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
  children: widget.models.map((EventListModel model) {
    return EventListItem(
      model: model,
    );
  }).toList(),
);
 }
```

}

How can I update this `ListView` from the place, where I instantiate my `EventList`? Thanks!

P.S. I am looking for something like `notifyDataSetChanged()` from Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify your `List` in the parent `Widget`, you must call `setState()`. The child `Widget` is going to get the updated `List`.